# Why is it called a "Wideawake Hat?"

Tags: etymology

This [website shows a picture of a "Wideawake Hat"](http://www.historyinthemaking.org/catalogue/menhat.html) or a Quaker Hat. How on earth did a hat come to be named "Wideawake"?

Comment: It's in the dictionary: "ORIGIN mid 19th cent.: punningly so named, because the hat does not have a nap."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why  this jocular expression has been originally used to refer to a hat with a low crown and a very wide brim, the "World Wide Words" notes that:

> - The [wide-awake](http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/ar-gal2.htm) was a soft felt hat with a broad brim and a low crown, ***said to have been jocularly named because it had no nap.***  It’s mentioned in Scouting for Boys by Robert Baden-Powell of 1908 and also here:
>
>   - And lastly there was the wagoner himself, a lad, say, of eighteen summers, a fine, strong, healthy-looking young fellow, well clad, and wearing on his head a “raddidoo” or wide-awake hat, with perhaps a peacock’s feather or some other embellishment at the side.
>   - The British Workman Past and Present, by The Reverend M C F Morris, 1928. Raddidoo defeats me completely, as it did the author, who remarked it was “used in the East Riding for the ordinary wide-awake hat commonly worn by the farm lads. ***The origin of this curious word I have never been able to discover”.***